# Amend not replace Active Directory Account information with powershell

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, active-directory

We are changing our phone system and as a result we need to update users telephone numbers on their active directory profile.

Currently each person has just the extension in the telephone field in their profile.
I would like to run a powershell script that will add digits to the front of this field, without replacing the extension that is already there.

Can this be done?

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: I don't really know where to discuss this so I shall do it here. My posts often get edited to remove my ending which is always "Kind Regards Matt". What is the reason for removing a polite closing, thanking people for any contribution they make. I might understand the removal of the name, but its my name and I should make the judgement to put it there or not, also its not like I use a fancy username to mask my name, so what is the point in removing it?

Comment: Probably an automated edit by the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, string concatenation in PowerShell can be used.

You don't have what you are using to get AD information, but from a purely functional standpoint you can use this as an example:

```
$phone = "4567"
$phone = "123-$phone"
```

Run that in a powershell console, and you will see the new value of $phone is "123-4567".

The more realistic scenario however is likely a 2 liner (I loved QAD Tools and the OOB options I might now remember as well)

```
$phone = (Get-ADUser "SamAccountName" -properties Telephonenumber | Select TelephoneNumber).TelephoneNumber
Set-AdUser -Profile "SamAccountName" -TelephoneNumber "123-$phone"
```